# Which pool image is better for executing an exe (.Net Framework 4.5) with faster scale out on azure batch service?

Tags: .net, azure, .net-4.0, scale, azure-batch

I am new to Azure Batch Service.

I have successfully created the application, job, and tasks. My batch service is running fine.
I have an issue with a longer scale-out time.
My batch service pool is taking almost 3 minutes to scale-out and be ready to process the tasks.
I need it to scale out faster.
My current pool image selection is this:
[image]

I have also tried with 2019-datacenter-core-smalldisk

but still got the same result.

I just want to run an exe on that processes a file in blob container. My application is not downloading any file on the local server.
RDP is also not required for my application. So the server just with CMD will be enough for me.
My exe application is in .Net Framework 4.5 (Not .Net Core)

Which image type will best fit my requirement?

Also. I am not able to find any proper documentation of all these image types that explains the difference between each of them.
If anyone knows please share the link to that documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information of all supported images using [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/account/listsupportedimages) operation.

Consider using **Automatic scaling** to gain faster scale outs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-automatic-scaling

Comment: Does this help you?